# H2 statement pooling

Tags: java, jdbc, h2

The reason to use prepared statements are twofold:

1. Prevent SQL injection by adding data from the outside world only as parameters.
2. Improve performance by letting the DB pre-parse the statement once and re-use it many times by just passing the parameters.

But prepared statements in JDBC are tied in with a connection. And we should use connection pooling. This means in a typical code sample I have to

- obtain a connection from the pool
- (re)-create the prepared statement every time, because there is no other sensible way to get it back

When using JdbcConnectionPool, the simple connection pool that comes with H2, I think statements are not cached. Does it mean there is rather a negative impact on performance when using prepared statements --- which I can not really avoid due to (1) above.

Comment: "I think statements are not cached" - why do you think that?

Comment: `% grep -i statement src/java/biz/source_code/miniConnectionPoolManager/MiniConnectionPoolManager.java`
has no results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

H2 caches prepared statements transparently on the connection level. Meaning, as long as the SQL string is the same when you create a prepared statement and you are using the same connection *it is not re-parsed*, but only compared as opaque string for the cache lookup (see `org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection#prepareCommand(...)`).

You can configure the query cache size with the parameter `QUERY_CACHE_SIZE`—more info [here](https://www.h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/engine/DbSettings.html#queryCacheSize).

Depending on your usage scenario, you might want to experiment with not using a connection pool at all. E.g. as embedded database, you don't really have high connection costs. You might experience a greater performance gain when using only a single connection (more cache hits; lower memory consumption, because you don't duplicate your caches). Also, many parts of H2 aren't (AFAIK) really built for concurrency.

So to answer your question:

No, I don't think here is a negative impact per se on prepared statement performance. To the contrary.

However, think about what kind of pool you want to use and how big you want it to be. Also, what kind of concurrency do you expect? Then measure both speed and memory consumption in the kind of scenario you expect to see in your live application. And... think about how relevant this really is for your application. I suspect there's probably bigger fish to fry elsewhere.

Comment: Aha, found it in `Session.prepareLocal()`. Thanks for the pointer. As for the real performance differences, these are not really an issue. I just wanted to completely understand the impact in case I come across this in a project where it may count. Regarding the pooling: I just read that H2 connections are synchronized, so a single connection would be sufficient indeed. But to stay compatible with general JDBC contracts, I rather use the pool.

Comment: Looks like the referenced link isn't working any more; [this seems more recent](https://www.h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/engine/DbSettings.html#queryCacheSize)

Comment: The re-use of prepared statements are a bit complicated. For a prepared statement to be able to be re-used, it must first be closed. Closing it ends the transaction, so you don't want to close it until the transaction is done.

So, for every call to `connection.prepareStatement(sql)`, you will always get a new prepared statement that parses all the SQL from scratch, as long as the statement has not been closed. So inside a transaction, multiple calls with the same exact SQL does not seem to re-use the prepared statement.